# Suppose $X \in [-1, 1]$ is a random variable, and $A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. Is $E[X]E[AX] - E[XAX]$ positive semi-definite?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, positive-semidefinite

Let $X \in [-1, 1]$ denote a random variable. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ denote a random positive semi-definite (PSD) matrix. $X$ and $A$ are dependent. Let $E$ denote expectation.

My question is:

Does $$v^TE[X]E[AX]v \geq 0 \Longrightarrow v^TE[XAX]v \geq 0?$$

By Hölder's inequality, for two random variables $X, Y$,
$$E[XY] \leq E(|X|)E(|Y|)$$
Therefore, I'm wondering if something similar would hold in case where $Y$ is a matrix.

Comment: We need $X \in \mathbb R^n$, right?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery $X \in \mathbb{R}$. It's a $1 \times 1$ random variable

Comment: @AugustoSantos $X$ and $A$ are dependent. I'll add this to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since $A$ is positive semidefinite, then
$$
v^{\top}\mathsf{E}[X^2A]v=\mathsf{E}[v^{\top}X^2Av]\ge 0
$$
because $v^{\top}X^2Av\ge 0$ for any $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.